# JQuery not displaying full width Chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the jquery chosen select and have one set to hidden and if anothers value is selected then the hidden one is shown. It works but when the second chosen is shown it is not the full width it should be.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="textfield1" class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Month: <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-4 controls">
        <select class="form-control input-sm chosen" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Choose a date..." data-rule-required="true" name="" id="month-list">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="FIRST_DAY_RENTAL_PERIOD">First day of rental period</option>
            <option value="LAST_DAY_RENTAL_PERIOD" >Last day of rental period</option>
            <option value="FIRST_CAL_DAY" >First calendar day</option>
            <option value="FIRST_CAL_DAY_PRORATE_DAY" >First calendar day (pro-rate daily)</option>
            <option value="FIRST_CAL_DAY_PRORATE_WEEK" >First calendar day (pro-rate weekly)</option>
            <option value="DAY_OF_MONTH">Specified day of month</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="month-days">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textfield1" class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 control-label">Day: <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-4 controls">
            <select class="form-control input-sm chosen" tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Choose a date..." data-rule-required="true" name="" id="">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery below works ok but once the chosen appears it looks like this. http://awesomescreenshot.com/01a1vuw8a1 It should show up the same width as the month above it

```
$('.month-days').hide();
$('#month-list').change(function(){
    if($("option:selected", this).val() == 'DAY_OF_MONTH'){
        $('.month-days').slideDown('fast');
    }else{
        $('.month-days').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of $("option:selected", this).val() 
you can use $(this).val()

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: It seems this is a CSS issue, did you specify width property for the select?

Comment: Yes width is set it works fine, the Month is an exacty copy of code. Its a problem with once it is made visible

Comment: If i do $('.month-days').hide(); and straight after it $('.month-days').show(); it appears as normal. It seems to be only when the show is a result of a click or change function then it doesnt apprear as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago, here is my proposal:

At first add #day-list id to second dropdown.

Add an event listener to first (#month-list) dropdown

```
$('select#month-list').on(
    'chosen:ready', 
    function() {//fires when first chosen dropdown is ready
        var mlCssWidth = $('select#month-list').closest('.chosen-container').css('width');
        //init second chosen after first one is ready
        $('select#day-list').chosen({/*other options*/, width: mlCssWidth});
    }
);
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
$('select#month-list').on(
    'chosen:updated', //or change?
    function() {
        var mlCssWidth = $('select#month-list').closest('.chosen-container').css('width');
        //correct second chosen width after first one is changed (and may have changed it's width if it was not hardocoded)
        $('select#day-list').closest('.chosen-container').css('width', mlCssWidth);
});
```

Of course you can cache jQuery objects/functions for simplification/performance.

PS: It would be simplier if you put it in jsfiddle ;-)

Comment: I managed to get it sorted myself by going in and adding width to the chzn div that gets generated. Its a strange one so it is

Answer (score 9):

Change chosen.js

```
container_props = {
        'class': container_classes.join(' '),
        'style': "width: " + (this.container_width()) + ";",
        'title': this.form_field.title
};
```

to

```
container_props = {
        'class': container_classes.join(' '),
        'style': "width: 100%;",
        'title': this.form_field.title
};
```

works for me ;)

Comment: Rather than changing the chosen.js file and needing to change it again each time you update chosen, you can set it like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27839342/153797 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/33796409/153797

Answer (score 7):

## Try this...

```
$("selector").chosen({
   width: '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('selector').chosen('destroy'); 
$("selector").chosen({ width: '100%' });
```

or

```
$("selector").data("chosen").destroy().chosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before hiding the second select element, call `$('second-selector').chosen();`
then hide the element.

Later when you show your element, the actual width will appear on the element.